# Should Hindus eat food objects of non-Indian origin?

Tags: scripture, food, plants

Apart from the usual ban on onion, garlic, radish, carrot & mushrooms, the sacred kitchen of Jagannatha Dhama in Sriksetra also bans the usage of vegetables of non-Indian origin like potato, tomato, pumpkin, capsicum & chilli which have become common ingredients in Indian kitchens (including Hindu ones). From logic, it can be inferred that those which have been refused by Jagannatha for consumption, are by default inedible for Hindus. I want to know the scriptural injuctions (both for & against) regarding this inference.

Comment: Well, without the words for the new world foods (at least identifiably) being in Sanskrit it is hard to tell if they are banned. Thus, they might just be being safe.

Comment: @Aupakarana Abhibhaa That's equivalent to saying that Hindus should abhor medicines not mentioned in Ayurveda. Secondly, potato does have a Sanskrit name (आलूकम्). Thirdly, the temple administration isn't averse to reform. When M.M Chandrasekhara Mahapatra reformed the Surya Siddhata (the basis of Odia calendar), the temple administration was quick to reform their timing of rituals to that of Mahapatra's 'Siddhanta Darpana' while majority of the Bengali Hindu society (which also follows the Surya Siddhanta) chose to continue the old standards.

Comment: Well, I'm just giving their reasoning. Also, there are no forbidden medicines mentioned (you could always inject it rather than eating)/, so there being some not mentioned would be weird.